# select a dropdown option loaded via ajax with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this dropdown with options that are loaded via AJAX. I am trying to auto select the first option from dropdown `wpce-1`. The second dropdown id `wpce-1` is still not loaded because need to select option from dropdown id `wpce-0`.

The second dropdown option loads only when `wpce-0` option is selected

```js
$('#wpce-1 option:not([disabled]):nth(1)')
  .attr('selected', 'selected')
  .prop('selected', true)
  .trigger('change')
  .get(0)
  .click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpce-field">
  <label for="wpce-0">Make</label>
  <select class="wpce-field-term" id="wpce-0" data-level="0" data-required="yes" data-required-message="" data-type="term">
    <option value="">Make</option>
    <option value="9554">ALFA ROMEO</option>
    <option value="9642">ASTON MARTIN</option>
    <option value="9663">AUDI</option>
    <option value="9873">BENTLEY</option>
    <option value="9916">BMW</option>
    <option value="10240">CHEVROLET</option>
    <option value="10282">CHRYSLER</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="wpce-field">
  <label for="wpce-1">Model</label>
  <select class="wpce-field-term" id="wpce-1" data-level="1" data-required="yes" data-required-message="" data-type="term">
    <option value="">Model</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what really is your question here ?

Comment: @FarzBhullar how to select an option from unloaded dropdown options

Comment: I think we need to see the rest of your code to better understand your question.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what `$('#wpce-1 option:not([disabled]):nth(1)')
  .attr('selected', 'selected')
  .prop('selected', true)
  .trigger('change')
  .get(0)
  .click();` is trying to do since that select option list is basically empty - aside from the fact that this code is "wrong"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all you have in mind so let's have a bit of fun here.

Perhaps you wish to go get new models and then append them as options.  I leave the way you go get models (ajax?) to you and use a fake array of name value pairs, sort it then append it as new options here by triggering

```js
let fakemodels = [{
    name: "My Name",
    value: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Wonder Wagon",
    value: "1234"
  },
  {
    name: "Beatnick Boat",
    value: "5634"
  },
  {
    name: "SuperView",
    value: "9834"
  },
  {
    name: "Guzzle",
    value: "1234455"
  },
  {
    name: "Wacky Wall",
    value: "8765"
  }
];

$('#wpce-0').on('change', function(event) {
  let selectedMake = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedMake);
  $('#wpce-1').trigger('load-models', [selectedMake, fakemodels])
});
$('#wpce-1').on('load-models', function(event, make, newValues) {
  console.log("Make:", make);
  // optional sort
  newValues.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    // names must be equal
    return 0;
  });
  console.log("Models:", newValues);
//append our new "models"
  let newOptions = $.map(newValues, (k, v) => $("<option/>").val(k.value).text(k.name));
  //  console.log("newOptions:",newOptions);
  $(this).append(newOptions);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpce-field">
  <label for="wpce-0">Make</label>
  <select class="wpce-field-term" id="wpce-0" data-level="0" data-required="yes" data-required-message="" data-type="term">
    <option value="">Make</option>
    <option value="9554">ALFA ROMEO</option>
    <option value="9642">ASTON MARTIN</option>
    <option value="9663">AUDI</option>
    <option value="9873">BENTLEY</option>
    <option value="9916">BMW</option>
    <option value="10240">CHEVROLET</option>
    <option value="10282">CHRYSLER</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="wpce-field">
  <label for="wpce-1">Model</label>
  <select class="wpce-field-term" id="wpce-1" data-level="1" data-required="yes" data-required-message="" data-type="term">
    <option value="">Model</option>
  </select>
</div>
```